# update values based on values from another table

Tags: db2

I have a table (Table A) in DB2 where a columns needs to be updated based on values from values from Table B.

e.g.

**Table A** has two columns and following data.

```
 ID    LOGIN
 01    DONALD.TRUMP
 02    BARACK.OBAMA
 03    ABRAHAM.LINCOLN
```

**Table B** has the following data.

```
 ID    OLDLOGIN            NEWLOGIN
 01    DONALD.TRUMP        DONALD.T
 02    ABRAHAM.LINCOLN     ABRAHAM.LIN
```

I want to update Table A's LOGIN value, give them the NEWLOGIN values if they exist in OLDLOGIN in Table B.

So the final result in Table A should be like below

```
 ID    LOGIN
 01    DONALD.T
 02    BARACK.OBAMA
 03    ABRAHAM.LIN
```

What would be the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume LUW and a recently new one. Probably clearest to do with a MERGE statement like:

```
MERGE INTO TA
USING (
    SELECT OLDLOGIN, NEWLOGIN
    FROM TB
) AS TB
    ON TA.LOGIN = TB.OLDLOGIN
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET LOGIN = NEWLOGIN ;
```

You can also do it with a traditional UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE TA
    SET LOGIN = ( SELECT NEWLOGIN 
                  FROM TB 
                  WHERE OLDLOGIN = TA.LOGIN )
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM TB
    WHERE OLDLOGIN = TA.LOGIN 
);
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked great. What would this query in such situation e.g.
If an user login are swapped.
barack.obama new id is Donald.trump
while donald.trump new id is barack.obama
How will it cater that?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand your question, can you add sample data and what you would like to happen?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
update tablea f1
set f1.login=
(
    select f2.newlogin from tableb f2
    where f1.oldlogin=f2.newlogin
    fetch first rows only
)
where exists
(
    select * from tableb f2
    where f1.oldlogin=f2.newlogin
)
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. Code only answers tend to be ill-received around here so if you could add a little explanation you could certainly improve your answer

Comment: The joins should be based on the login columns, not on id.