# Update a table based on another table

Tags: mariadb

I have `Cars` and `Numbers` tables, both of them have `car_id` column. I need to update `Cars` table like that:

```
update Cars set Status='old' where serial_num=44;
```

my tables are like that:

```
cars  
car_id    status
1           new
2           new
3           new
Numbers
car_id    serial_num
1           54
2           44
3           66
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update values based on values from another table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173215/update-values-based-on-values-from-another-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, you want something like this?

```
UPDATE c
SET Status = 'old'
FROM Cars c
INNER JOIN Numbers n ON c.car_id = n.car_id
WHERE n.serial_num=44;
```

The `FROM` portion is just like a normal select statement, but you specify in the `UPDATE` which of your tables will be updated.

And since you've done so, it knows that `Status` is in c, not n, so `c.Status` is optional.